# конвертировать строку

Tags: python

Всем привет,

есть строка в таком виде:

```
str1 = ('some_data1', 'some_data2', 774, 60, 714)
```

нужно конвертировать в такую строку:

```
str2 = some_data1,some_data2,774,60,714
```

пробовал через цикл for:

```
for i in str1:
    str = str +''.join(i)
    list.append(str)
```

но получаю ошибку:

```
str = str +''.join(i)
TypeError
```

краткое описание задачи, есть к примеру 100 строк такого типа, нужно обработать каждую строку, передать в список, затем из списка записать в csv  файл, проблема в том что csv хранит строку в формате: строка1,строка2,строка3, без скобок и доп знаков, пробовал конвертировать строку с помощю join перед записью в файл, но просто добавляет скобки, спасибо за советы. P.S: Или нужно обрабатвать переменную в том моменте когда я ее добавляю в строку?(в пирмере этого нет)

Comment: То, что имеется - не строка. То, что нужно получить  - тоже не строка.

Answer (score 2):

В круглых скобках это кортежи. Используем для преобразования объектов кортежа в текст функцию `str`, `map` позволит пробежаться по списку и применить функцию в наиболее короткой форме:

```
str1 = ('some_data1', 'some_data2', 774, 60, 714)
print type(str1)
# <type 'tuple'>
print ",".join(map(str,str1))
# some_data1,some_data2,774,60,714
```

Если делать через цикл, то можно следующим образом:

```
str2 = ""
for i in str1:
    if str1.index(i) == 0:
        str2 += "{}".format(i)
    else:
        str2 += ",{}".format(i)
print str2
```

`format` в коробке сам преобразует типы (в данном случае `int` в `str`) аналогично функции `str`, но и еще позволяет удобно форматировать строки

Плюс старайтесь избегать названия переменных аналогично названиям типов, команд и т.п. (в том числе `str`, `import`, `if` и т.д.)

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable по первому примеру ошибка? можете почему аргументы map это str,str1?

Comment: у вас где переменная такая есть скорей всего `str` - в которой текст. Ваша ошибка воспроизводиться `print ""()` - удалите переменную `str`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
str1 = ('some_data1', 'some_data2', 774, 60, 714)
str1 = [str(item) for item in str1]
str2 = ','.join(str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str2 = ','.join(map(str, str1))
```

---

Содержание строки `str2` после этого будет:

> ```
> 'some_data1,some_data2,774,60,714'
> ```

---

Объяснение:

1. `map(str, str1)` применит функцию `str` *для всякого элемента кортежи `str1`*.
2. `','.join()` затем *соединит все эти элементы в единую строку*, отделяя их запятами.